# Impossible to db:seed laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-7

Good morning,

I can't send data from my factory to my database.

```sh
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'genre_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `books` (`isbn`, `title`, `publish_date`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (4243421897, Prof., 1992-09-08 00:57:41, 2020-03-10 15:02:36, 2020-03-10 15:02:36))
```

I don't know if in my migrations I have to specify that my foreign_keys don't have default values...

These are my files:

create_books_table.php

```php
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            $table->id('isbn');
            $table->string('title' , 100);
            $table->text('cover')->nullable();
            $table->date('publish_date');
            $table->bigInteger('genre_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('author_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('genre_id')
                ->references('id')->on('Genres')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('author_id')
                ->references('id')->on('Authors')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')->on('Readers')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

BookFactory.php

```php
$factory->define(Book::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'isbn' => $faker->isbn10,
        'title' => $faker->title,
        'publish_date' => $faker->dateTime()
    ];
});
```

I haven't yet created a 'Route' in my web.php so I haven't done the CRUD too, I haven't even modified my blades but I just want to set up my whole database for the moment.
But I wonder if that's not the problem.

Here's a schematic from my database : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/smMZU.jpg
(I'm not allowed to upload images yet. )

*(i'm in  coding school)*

Thank you!

Comment: Look at your error again. `Field 'genre_id' doesn't have a default value`, and you're only inserting `isbn`, `title`, `publish_date`, plus timestamps. Either make `genre_id` nullable, or pass one in.

Comment: @aynber Thank you, I'll try that, I thought so, but I don't dare to touch the foreign keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined your `genre_id` column as being required, or always containing a value. Your insert query, though, is not including a `genre_id` value. In this case, MySQL will fall back to look for a default value configured for the column, but you haven't defined one.

A default value doesn't make much sense for a foreign key style column like `genre_id`, unless you have a specific reason to specify a default ID to be used when one isn't explicitly provided.

The better choice would be to make the column `nullable`, or able to use a `NULL` value instead of an existing ID. Modify the line in your migration to:

```php
$table->bigInteger('genre_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

When a foreign key column is `nullable`, it won't perform any assertions for the `NULL` value, only non-null values.